# Generic nearest value search method for collections

Tags: java, search, collections, iterator

I have created a method to find a value closest to a selected value in a collection. I have no idea if it will work because I don't know how to write a test case for it in Junit. Will this method work or any ideas for a test case. nearest is determined by distance. Due to restrictions I cannot use array lists for this method.

### Telemeter

```
  public interface Telemeter<E> extends Comparator<E> {

   /**
    * Returns the distance between e1 and e2.
    *
    * @param e1 the first object
    * @param e2 the second object
    * @return the distance between e1 and e2
    *
    */

   public double distance(E e1, E e2);



}
```

### Method for nearest

```
    /**
    * Return the element of c nearest to val.
    * The Collection c is not changed as a result of calling this method.
    *
    * @param <T> the type variable for this method
    * @param c the Collection to be searched
    * @param val the reference value
    * @param tm the Telemeter that measures distance
    * @return the element e in c such that its distance from
    * val is minimum for all elements in c
    *
    */
   public static <T> T nearest(Collection<T> c, T val, Telemeter<T> tm) {
      if (c == null || c.size() == 0 || tm == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
      T answer = null;
      Iterator<T> itr = c.iterator();
      T one = itr.next();       
      while(itr.hasNext()) {

         T two = itr.next();
         if(Math.abs((tm.distance(one, val))) > Math.abs(tm.distance(two, val))) {
         answer = two; 
         }
      }    
      return answer;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.. but you have to update "one" otherwise you will always be comparing the distance with the first element of the collection. Try this:

```
Iterator<T> itr = c.iterator();
T answer = itr.next();       
while(itr.hasNext()) {

    T two = itr.next();
    if(Math.abs((tm.distance(answer, val))) > Math.abs(tm.distance(two, val))) {
    answer = two; 
    }
}    
return answer;
```

And I agree with ATG that you definitely should write some test cases for code you write. Try to test  simple scenarios, as well as more complicated scenarios such as when you have duplicates in your array, values that are smaller than any element in the array (your code should return the lowest element), and so on.

Comment: How would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in that your code returns `null` in a collection with a single element, whereas it should probably return the single element.

To be honest, though, you **really should** write some kind of test.  If you're not comfortable with JUnit, TestNG etc. and absolutely don't have time to learn then you can write a simple main method and just play with values until you're happy.  Asking the SO community for help *may* catch bugs in the immediate term but as you refactor this code then you'll have no proof that it continues to work as expected.